# best way to insert data using dephi in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi

I've always used such script to insert data into a table in delphi 7

```
sql := 'INSERT INTO table_foo (field1,field2,field3) VALUES ('
+quotedstr('value1')
+','+quotedstr('value2')
+','+quotedstr('value3')
+')';
adoquery1.close;
adoquery1.sql.text := sql;
adoquery1.execsql;
```

but one of my friend just showed me another way that looks cleaner, like so:

```
sql := 'SELECT * FROM table_foo';
adoquery1.close;
adoquery1.sql.text := sql;
adoquery1.open;
adoquery1.insert;
adoquery1.fieldbyname('field1').asstring := quotedstr('value1');
adoquery1.fieldbyname('field2').asstring := quotedstr('value2');
adoquery1.fieldbyname('field3').asstring := quotedstr('value3');
adoquery1.post;
```

which of the two methods are better (faster, easier to read/debug)? especially when the data in `table_foo` is large or there are a lot more fields to fill.

Comment: I did not even know that second syntax ;-)

Comment: You should read about *[cursors](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ms181441.aspx)* in general and about *updatable* cursors in particular. Latter is the thing which allows your friend to use that trick. Of course, basic statement is not burdened by overhead of client cursor allocation.

Answer (score 9):

If you do use `INSERT INTO` statements use parameters (for reasons of readability, avoid SQL injection, SQL caching) e.g.:

```
adoquery1.sql.text := 'INSERT INTO table_foo (field1, field2) values (:field1, :field2)';
adoquery1.Parameters.ParamByName('field1').Value := value1;
adoquery1.Parameters.ParamByName('field2').Value := value2;
```

I **prefer** the second way (with a small tweak which I'll explain). 
Since you are inserting one record, the tweak is to select an *empty* recordset i.e.:

```
SELECT * FROM table_foo where 1=0
```

This way you don't select *all* records form the table.
Also no need to use `QuotedStr` when assigning the values i.e.:

```
adoquery1.FieldByName('field1').AsString := 'value1';
```

The main reason I use this method is because it's easy to read and to maintain.
I don't need to bother myself with pure SQL queries. I don't need to deal with Parameters which sometime required to specify the data type for the parameters (e.g. `Parameters.ParamByName('field1').DataType := ftInteger`). No need to `ParseSQL`.
I simply use the DataSet `As(Type)` e.g.

```
FieldByName('field1').AsBoolean := True;
```

I would also prefer to use this method if I need to insert multiple records in a single transaction.
The downside for the second method is the short trip to the SQL server via `SELECT FROM`.

Another option would be to create a SQL stored procedure, pass your values to the SP, and write all the SQL logic inside the SP.

Comment: Even with the `WHERE 1=0`, the second option does still incur an overhead of an extra DB round-trip to obtain schema information. So you may want to take some steps to reduce the overhead. I.e. Reuse the dataset instance for multiple inserts as far as possible. (It might be okay to `Close` the dataset, and provided you don't change the SQL query it will remember the schema. However, I'm unsure - so you'll have to double-check.)

Comment: +1 for Parameters:) One big reason why one would prefer the INSERT syntax is when you want to do BULK INSERTS which is way faster.

Comment: Note that calling `PrepareCursor` on a query can also significantly increase execution speed.

Answer (score 1):

The second approach demands more local resources from the dataset, since it will keep a memory of the original result set and then use that memory to decide which records should be sent to the server by using which SQL statement. That approach also requires a live connection with the server and a bidirectional local cursor set in the dataset. `TADODataset` does all that for you. It works more to you work less, but it will consume more from the system. The decison, under my view, depends on which resource is more important, your time or computer resources.

Personaly, I prefer using `TClientDataset` (CDS). It will allow you to have an in-memory dataset and by using `TDatasetProvider.BeforeUpdateRecord` event in the corresponding `TDatasetProvider` you will get the best of both worlds: absolute control over which sentence will be submited to the server and a flexible and bidirectinal dataset that works very well on GUIs.

Besides (this is the most important to me), with CDS you will be able to isolate the specifics of your DBMS away from the main logic of your application, because that logic will be operating on a DB-independent dataset. If you have to shift from ADO to, let´s say, DBX, your main code will not be hurt because it´s written on CDS.

Comment: +1 for "requires a live connection with the server and a bidirectional local cursor set in the dataset". Which I never mentioned in my answer, assuming default ADO settings.